# dlsym: undefined symbol, Android N

Tags: android, c++, linux, shared-libraries, elf

I would like to read value from the Android runtime shared library in my application.
Since Android 5, when the new runtime was introduced and `libart.so` has first appeared, I am doing it successfully with this code:

```
 std::unique_ptr<void, int(*)(void*)> handle { 
     dlopen("libart.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL),
     &dlclose
 };

constexpr char THREAD_KEY_NAME[] = "_ZN3art6Thread17pthread_key_self_E";
key_ = static_cast<pthread_key_t *>(dlsym(handle.get(), THREAD_KEY_NAME));

LOG("Current thread: ", key_);
```

I'm testing this code on Android N simulator, and it fails! `dlsym` returns:

```
undefined symbol: _ZN3art6Thread17pthread_key_self_E
```

I think "OK, there is no symbol now", so I pull the libart.so from simulator and see:

```
% ./i686-linux-android-nm ~/Desktop/libart.so | grep pthread_key
00736ea0 B _ZN3art6Thread17pthread_key_self_E
```

hmm...

```
% ./i686-linux-android-objdump -T ~/Desktop/libart.so | grep pthread_key
00736ea0 g    DO .bss   00000004  Base        .protected _ZN3art6Thread17pthread_key_self_E
```

hmm..

```
  % ./i686-linux-android-readelf -a ~/Desktop/libart.so | grep pthread_key_self
  %
```

OK, empty there :(

So, while I'm not fully expert in these things, i have some questions:

1. Why is `readelf` output is empty? There is some flags i forgot?
2. What does `.protected` means in objdump output? I have read some things about it but don't really understand. May be you can get good explanation?
3. Why `dlsym` returns error on new versions of Android? What the difference?

BTW, I dumped `/proc/self/maps` file for my application on both Android versions and `grep libart.so` gives me:

- Android L (which works fine):

  ```
  b40f3000-b45f3000 r-xp 00000000 1f:00 777        /system/lib/libart.so
  b45f3000-b45fb000 r--p 004ff000 1f:00 777        /system/lib/libart.so
  b45fb000-b45fc000 rw-p 00507000 1f:00 777        /system/lib/libart.so
  ```
- Android N (does not work):

  ```
  aaef1000-aaef2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 729        /system/fake-libs/libart.so
  aaef2000-aaef3000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 729        /system/fake-libs/libart.so
  aaef3000-aaef4000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 729        /system/fake-libs/libart.so


  abc53000-ac373000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1034       /system/lib/libart.so
  ac374000-ac37c000 r--p 00720000 fd:00 1034       /system/lib/libart.so
  ac37c000-ac37e000 rw-p 00728000 fd:00 1034       /system/lib/libart.so
  ```

Thanks for any information!

**upd**: I see there is two libart.so on Android N, and /system/fake-libs/libart.so is empty. I suppose there is a problem, but dlopen("/system/lib/libart.so", ...) does not works :(

Answer (score 1):

In Android N you can not open some private so file(https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk)

But you can open libart.so for Android-N use this:
https://github.com/crmulliner/adbi/blob/master/hijack/hijack.c 
or 
https://github.com/avs333/Nougat_dlfunctions