# C++ linux: How to get an exported function's address from a loaded library?

Tags: android, c++, linux, shared-libraries

I've tried to approch this the default way, dlopen the library and dlsym it. But when I dlopen it, this error pops up:
`dlopen failed: library "libfmod.so" not found: needed by /.../libSwordsman.so in namespace (default)`

However, when I go into proc/self/maps, the libfmod.so **is loaded**, but the dlopen still refuses to load libSwordsman.so. After reading some docs, I used RTLD_NOLOAD to test if it can retrive the handle, but it returns null, which means its **not loaded** acc to the docs.

`dlopen failed: library "/.../libSwordsman.so" wasn't loaded`

But I clearly see its loaded in the /proc/self/maps file. And dladdr the Base Address I found in proc/maps returns a vaild Dl_info pointer with the correct value. So maybe this library didnt get loaded via dlopen? I searched about other ways to load a library, and found nothing. I was going to use the dladdr1 api with the flag RTLD_DL_LINKMAP to retrive a pointer to a link_map (which is the "handle" that dlopen gives you but in void*) but I realize that android dont have this api.

So now my best bet is to use the base addr and calc every function offset to it, but I would prefer dlsym to save time if you guys can think of a way to obtain this so's handle.

Comment: You can use `dlsym` w/o `dlopen`. Use it with `RTLD_DEFAULT`. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html

Comment: doesnt work. The lib is marked "not loaded" in dlopen,  so the dlsym wont look inside it too. (guessed fail reason)

Comment: I use it all the time on non-android Linux. If it doesn't work then android probably blocked it. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44023987/5128211

Answer (score 1):

Your problem X is this:

`dlopen failed: library "libfmod.so" not found: needed by /.../libSwordsman.so in namespace (default)`

This means that ELF-header of `libSwordsman.so` doesn't contain the path to find `libfmod.so`.

The solution is using option `-Wl,-rpath,/some/where/lib/` when linking `libSwordman.so`

Explanation: loading-time, the dependent libraries have to be found in the file-system, even if they are already loaded into memory.

It is not enough that a library with the same name (libfmod.so) is already loaded: the device/inode numbers have to match. (To verify the matching, the loader first finds the shared library in the file-system using the `rpath` (or `runpath`) entries in the main executable and/or the calling shared object.)

Note: calling `dlopen(RTLD_NOLOAD)` doesn't help before a successful load of that library. (For example, if I want a dlopen-handle to glibc (`libc.so.6`), I can use `RTLD_NOLOAD`, because it is quite likely to have been already loaded.)

Comment: But why the dlopen with flag RTLD_NOLOAD says its not loaded?